# How to move div to unique li id with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML, the `id` from `li` is generated automatically from PHP.

```
<ul>
  <li id="1">content</li> //comment
  <div id="will-append-to-li-id-1"></div> //parent comment
  <li id="2">content</li>
  <li id="3">content</li> //comment
  <div id="will-append-to-li-id-3"></div> //parent comment
  <li id="..">more content</li>
</ul>
```

I want to move `div` to `li id="1"` and have tried this method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("ul > li + div#will-append-to-li-id-1").appendTo("ul > li");
});
```

This works fine, but the `div` also move to `li id="2"`, `li id="3"` and more.
How to make the div move to `li id="1"` only?

**Update**

This actual HTML code:

```
<ul class="comment-list">
  <li id="li-comment-1">
    <div class="content-comment">comment text here</div>
  </li>
  <ol class="child-comment"> <!-- child from li-comment-1 -->
    <div class="the-child-comment">parent comment text here</div>
  </ol>
  <li id="li-comment-2">
    <div class="content-comment">comment text here</div>
  </li>
  <li id="li-comment-3">
    <div class="content-comment">comment text here</div>
  </li>
  <ol class="child-comment"> <!-- child from li-comment-3 -->
    <div class="the-child-comment">parent comment text here</div>
  </ol>
</ul>
```

I want to move `<div class="the-child-comment">` to `<div class="content-comment">`
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will move all `div`s that are children of the `ul` to the previous `li`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul div').each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).prev('li'));
  });
});
```

Note that only `li`s are allowed to be direct children of a `ul`, so it's best if you could modify the PHP code that generates the invalid HTML.

**Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul div').each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).prev('li'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="1">content</li>//comment
  <div id="will-append-to-li-id-1"></div>//parent comment
  <li id="2">content</li>
  <li id="3">content</li>//comment
  <div id="will-append-to-li-id-3"></div>//parent comment
  <li id="..">more content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the li id automatic generated with PHP, so the id have dynamic unique number, your code work but it is not that.

Comment: If you want it to be appended to the *first* `li`, but you don't know what id the `li` has, then do:  `$('#will-append-to-li-id-1').appendTo('li:first');`

Comment: I *think* I understand what you're trying to do.  See my update.

Comment: work fine sir, but how to move <div id="append-to"> if <li id="1"> have parent <div> ., i try $(this).appendTo($(this).prev('li > div')); not working

Comment: If a `div` is a parent of the `li`, you would use `'div > li'` instead of `'li > div'`.  However, a `li`'s parent should *only* be an `ol` or `ul` according to the spec.

Comment: so parent <li> must be <ol> or <ul> instead <div> ? i try div > li but not working.,

Comment: Yes.  You haven't posted an example of a `div` being a parent of an `li`, so I don't know if I can help.

Comment: Your actual HTML is invalid, so I think you should focus on the PHP code instead of trying to fix it with jQuery.

Comment: now working sir, `$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.comment-list ol.children').each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).prev('.comment-list li'));
  });

  $('li.comment ol.children').each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).prev('div.bbp-reply-content-t'));
  });
});`

Answer (score 1):

Just specify #1?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("ul > li + div#will-append-to-li-id-1").appendTo("ul > li#1");
});
```

Edit: Based on your comment, try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $lis = $("ul > li");
   $li = $($lis[0]); // to get the first li
   $("ul > li + div#will-append-to-li-id-1").appendTo($li);
});
```

Comment: No, the li id generated with PHP so have diynamic number.

Comment: Then the ID isn't `1` as you described in the most. Either pass the dynamic number to your Javascript, or access the `n-th` element like this (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answer, considering making the least changes to your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("ul > li + div#will-append-to-li-id-1").appendTo("#1");
});
```

But to make your code cleaner, first it is not recommended to use a number as your ID, this is not supported by all browsers, but hopefully you used the numbers just for simplification purposes here. (make sure your id starts with a letter).

Also, the way you're showing this is not how .append() would work, .append() would actually add the div inside the list item so it would look like this:

```
<li id="1">content<div id="will-append-to-li-id-1"></div></li>
```

If what you want to happen is what you show in the example, then you'll need to use .insertAfter() instead.

you can also use

```
.appendTo('ul > li:first-child');
```